# Installing New 2020 Rockshox Reverb C1 Dropper Post

Tags: dropper

I bought a brand new Rockshox Reverb C1 dropper post off of ebay and it came in the wrapper with the hydraulic cable housing already connected to the lever. My problem now is how do I route the cable housing through the frame on my carbon frame? The port on the frame is formed to route the cable housing. My problem is that I can't figure out how to remove the new 2020 flat barb is on the end of the hose. That needs to be remove in order to put the hose through the frame. I tried to unscrew the barbs at both ends but they won't budge. I can't imagine that a brand new product would involve hacking up the cable housing and cutting the barbs out.

[image]

Comment: I haven’t seen one yet but know barbs at both ends on a 1x lever are threaded. Does a T10 fit in the barn like on the stealthamajig barbs?

Comment: Have you tried looking up a service manual for the seat post on SRAM's website? They have quite a lot of technical documentation PDFs there, which helped me several times. You can also try to reach SRAM's support; given that the seat post is very new, there may be some differences in its construction/cabling compared to older revisions, something not many people are aware about yet.

Comment: I've looked at the manual but they only briefly mention the barb on page 17 and never talk about how to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem, tried some force but no good. Then tried the torx tool which came in the box, fit perfectly in.

Clamped the hose and unscrewed, the barbs are threaded into the hydraulic hose!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/44363)

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I'm not much up on hydraulics - doesn't the last sentence say that the flat barb (I'd call it a lip)  should unthread if the hose is clamped  ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out to remove the 2020 dropper barb. I just had to grab the barb and the hose with some wrenches and with more force than I would have liked. I was worried about damaging both the barb and the hose but I think they both came out ok.